# CSS based on class presence condition

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I am new to CSS. In one use case I need to apply a CSS class, only when another is not present.

```
<div
  class="border-solid p-2 bg-white mt-1 h-fit"
  [ngClass]="SOME_CONDITION ? 'tile-container' : ''"
>
  <div class = 'chart-container'>
      <app-angualar-component></app-angualar-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

If **tile-container** class is present then **chart-container** class should not get applied and vice versa if *tile-container* is not present then *chart-container* class should get applied.

I need to achieve this via CSS only.

It looks a very common use case, but I didn't find any open/closed question which is getting fit into current use case.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can make use of the CSS sibling combinator (~) and the :not() pseudo-class selector.

```
<style>
  .chart-container {
  /* Your chart-container styles here */
 }

 .tile-container {
   /* Your tile-container styles here */
 }

 .chart-container:not(.tile-container) ~ .chart-container {
   /* Apply chart-container class only when tile-container class is not present also vise versa */
/* Add any additional styles you need */
 }
</style>

<div class="border-solid p-2 bg-white mt-1 h-fit">
  <div class="chart-container">
    <app-angualar-component></app-angualar-component>
  </div>
 </div>
```

In the above code, the 'chart-container:not(.tile-container) ~ .chart-container' selector targets elements with the chart-container class that do not have the tile-container class as their previous sibling. This way, when the tile-container class is present, the chart-container class will not be applied, and vice versa.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76456209/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).

Answer (score 0):

if you want just styling, you would have to override every `.chart-container` styles in `.tile-container` like

```
.chart-container{
  padding : 15px;
}

.tile-container .chart-container{
  padding : 30px !important;
}
```

doing this will apply tile container's css due to higher specificity

you can also do this instead

```
<div
  class="border-solid p-2 bg-white mt-1 h-fit">
  <div [ngClass]="SOME_CONDITION ? 'tile-container' : 'chart-container'">
      <app-angualar-component></app-angualar-component>
  </div>
</div>
```